# How to dir without showing extension (batch)

Tags: batch-file, dir

For example, I have the folder d:\temp\ and four word document files in it (.doc)

I know that

```
dir /b "d:\temp"
```

will give me

```
File1.doc
File2.doc
File3.doc
File4.doc
```

But how can I do it so that there are only file names without extensions?

like

```
File1
File2
File3
File4
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for %a in ("d:\temp\*") do @echo %~na
```

or for batch file:

```
for %%a in ("d:\temp\*") do @echo %%~na
```

to display also directories you can use:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /f "d:\temp\*"') do @echo %%~na
```

Comment: Perfect, except that OP's original command will display both files and folders, but your answer will only display files. Revert to FOR /F with 'DIR /B' if both files and folders are needed.

Comment: What does ~na stand for?

Comment: @ShadiNamrouti - it expands the parameter to its name only (without the expansion) - https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: How do I redirect this list to a text file?

Comment: @posfan12 with `... do (@echo %%~na>>"text.file")` ?

Answer (score 3):

Another version with slight differences from the ones above:

```
for /f %x in ('dir /b /on *.doc') do @echo %~nx
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code, when run via a batch file that uses @echo off, should work:

```
for /f "skip=7 tokens=5 delims=. " %%g in ('dir d:\temp') do echo %%g
```

Will print all file names without spaces in them.  Tested and does so for my F:\ thumb drive.

**Edit:**  `for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%g in ('dir /b d:\temp') do echo %%g`

Will print out files and directories in a given path with spaces and is simpler anyway.